# Mixed effects random forest (MERF) in Python: random slope or just intercept?

Tags: python, random-forest, random-effects-model

Does the [MERF](https://towardsdatascience.com/mixed-effects-random-forests-6ecbb85cb177) implementation in python allow for random slope effects?
If so, how?

I assume yes, and that it is achieved using the Z matrix. With a column of ones for the intercept and a column for the independent variable?

However, if that is the case, as the $b_i$ is drawn from a $N(0,\sigma_b)$ distribution, do these $b_i$ adjust an average slope? How is this information accessed in this implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does allow random slopes, trough matrix Z, as you rightly guessed.

the random slopes don't adjust an "average" fixed slope, but they adjust instead the random forest predictions $f(x)$, which of course is not linear, but it is the fixed part of the model.